# Error use of deleted function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a list of non blocking calls in first loop and then waiting in second loop. Why do i get deleted function ?

```
std::list< vendorClient>  vendorQ;
for (auto &addr : vendors_) {
    vendorClient vendor();
    vendor.someFunc();
    vendorQ.push_back(vendor);
 }

 // Now block till they finish up
 while (vendorQ.size() >0) {
    vendorClient ven = vendorQ.front(); // ERROR use of deleted function <<<
    vendorQ.pop_front();
    //  ..more stuff
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have `delete`d the copy constructor of `vendorClient`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please add the compiler error, and the `vendorClient` header definition.

Comment: You probably want to write `vendorClient vendor;` instead of `vendorClient vendor();` in the third line.

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor of `vendorClient` may have been explicitly declared deleted:

```
vendorClient(cosnt vendorClient &) = delete;
```

or have been deleted implicitly. The compiler may do this for [vary reasons](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). If so, you need to define explicitly a copy constructor for copy construct `ven`.

In fact, you can also try to move construct `ven`, since the instance which is held by `vendorQ` is destroyed immediately after.

```
vendorClient ven = std::move(vendorQ.front());
vendorQ.pop_front();
```